# Relationship $v_A^2-v_B^2=2a_t\Delta s $ for motion with constant tangential acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, energy-conservation, acceleration

I can not understand a relationship in the general motion in the plane. I am considering a point, which follows a curved trajectory. Indicate A and B two different position of the trajectory and $v_A$ and $v_B$ the modulus of the speed in those positions. Knowing that $a_t$ (the tangential acceleration which  is constant) and calling $\Delta s$ the distance between A e B.
Why

$$v_A^2-v_B^2=2a_t\Delta s $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation holds whenever there is [constant acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Constant_translational_acceleration_in_a_straight_line). Here are 2 ways of deriving that equation, which I hope help you understand it.

**Energy conservation**

The change in kinetic energy must be equal to the work done on the particle.
$$
\frac{1}{2}m v_A^2 - \frac{1}{2}mv_B^2 = \int F\cdot dx 
$$
For a constant force and mass $\int F\cdot dx = F (x_A - x_A) \cos(\theta) = ma \cos(\theta) \Delta s$. Further let $a_t = a \cos(\theta)$ and we get
$$
\frac{1}{2}m v_A^2 - \frac{1}{2}mv_B^2 = ma_t\Delta s
$$
Multiply both sides by $2$ and divide by $m$
$$
v_A^2 - v_B^2 = 2a_t\Delta s
$$

**Constant acceleration**

We can derive the same equation a different way by assuming the acceleration is constant.
$$
a = constant \\
v = \int a dt = a \int dt = at + c
$$
Consider $t = 0$ and see that $v(t=0) = c$, so $c$ is the initial velocity $u$.
$$
x = \int v dt = \int(u + at)dt = u \int dt + a\int t dt = ut + \frac{1}{2}at^2 + c_2 
$$
Again consider $t = 0$ and see that $x(t=0) = c_2$, so $c_2$ is the initial position $x_0$. Let's rewrite $x - x_0$ as $\Delta s$
$$
\Delta s = ut + \frac{1}{2}at^2
$$
Now we'll eliminate the $t$ dependence by plugging in $t = \frac{v-u}{a}$
$$
\Delta s = u\frac{v-u}{a} + \frac{1}{2}a(\frac{v-u}{a})^2 = (\frac{v-u}{2a}) (2u + v- u )  = (\frac{v-u}{2a}) (v + u) = \frac{1}{2a} (v^2 - u^2)     \\
v^2 = u^2 + 2a\Delta s
$$